# Output the Powershell Results to RichTextBox

Tags: powershell

Thanks for the help in advance

I have a Powershell Form with multiple buttons that call separate functions.
These functions will perform a series of tasks

What I cannot seem to get working is for the results of the execution (errors and all) to display into my Outputbox text box.

Instead it goes into the powershell console used to start the application, tried all the methods I could find on the internet, but I'm obviously mis-understanding how to do this.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  #loading the necessary .net libraries (using void to suppress output)
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "Azure Environment Build"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(850,675) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
#################################################################################################################################################################################################### Start functions
function Test-Variables {

$Outputbox.Appendtext = ($InputJSON)
#$Outputbox.AppendText = $ResourceINF
#$Outputbox.AppendText = $EnvCode
#$Outputbox.AppendText = $Location
#$Outputbox.AppendText = $Region

#$Outputbox.Appendtext = New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment -Name deployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceINF-NET-01 -TemplateFile -Verbose

}

function Stage1 {

write-host "stage 1"  

}

function Stage2 {

write-host "stage 2" 

}

function Stage3 {

write-host "stage 3" 

}

function Stage4 {

write-host "stage 4" 

}

function Stage5 {

write-host "stage 5" 

}

function Stage6 {

write-host "stage 6" 

}

function Stage7 {

write-host "stage 7" 

}

function Stage8 {

write-host "stage 8" 

}


function Stage9 {

write-host "stage 9" 

}


function Stage10 {

write-host "stage 10" 

}


function Stage11 {

write-host "stage 11" 

}


function Stage12 {

write-host "stage 12" 

}


#################################################################################################################################################################################################### End Function

#################################################################################################################################################################################################### Start Lines Section

$mypen = new-object Drawing.Pen red
$mypen.width = 3
$formGraphics = $form.createGraphics()
$form.add_paint({$formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen, 10, 65, 800, 65)})

$mypen2 = new-object Drawing.Pen green
$mypen2.width = 3
$formGraphics = $form.createGraphics()
$form.add_paint({$formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen2, 10, 165, 800, 165)})

$mypen1 = new-object Drawing.Pen blue
$mypen1.width = 3
$formGraphics = $form.createGraphics()
$form.add_paint({$formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen1, 10, 265, 800, 265)})


#################################################################################################################################################################################################### End Lines Section



#################################################################################################################################################################################################### Start Buttons

$Stage1Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage1Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,95)
$Stage1Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage1Button.Text = "Stage 1"
$Stage1Button.Add_Click({Stage1}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage1Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage2Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage2Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(210,95)
$Stage2Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage2Button.Text = "Stage 2"
$Stage2Button.Add_Click({Stage2}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage2Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage3Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage3Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(410,95)
$Stage3Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage3Button.Text = "Stage 3"
$Stage3Button.Add_Click({Stage3}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage3Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage4Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage4Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(610,95)
$Stage4Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage4Button.Text = "Stage 4"
$Stage4Button.Add_Click({Stage4}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage4Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage5Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage5Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,195)
$Stage5Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage5Button.Text = "Stage 5"
$Stage5Button.Add_Click({Stage5}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage5Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage6Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage6Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(210,195)
$Stage6Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage6Button.Text = "Stage 6"
$Stage6Button.Add_Click({Stage6}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage6Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage7Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage7Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(410,195)
$Stage7Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage7Button.Text = "Stage 7"
$Stage7Button.Add_Click({Stage7}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage7Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage8Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage8Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(610,195)
$StageButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage8Button.Text = "Stage 8"
$Stage8Button.Add_Click({Stage8}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage8Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage9Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage9Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,295)
$Stage9Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage9Button.Text = "Stage 9"
$Stage9Button.Add_Click({Stage9}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage9Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage10Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage10Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(210,295)
$Stage10Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage10Button.Text = "Stage 10"
$Stage10Button.Add_Click({Stage10}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage10Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage11Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage11Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(410,295)
$Stage11Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage11Button.Text = "Stage 11"
$Stage11Button.Add_Click({Stage11}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage11Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$Stage12Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Stage12Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(610,295)
$Stage12Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,60)
$Stage12Button.Text = "Stage 12"
$Stage12Button.Add_Click({Stage12}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($Stage12Button) #activating the button inside the primary window

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(245,370)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,23)
$OKButton.Text = "Test"
$OKButton.Add_Click({Test-Variables}) #the action triggered by the button
$Form.Controls.Add($OKButton) #activating the button inside the primary window

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(445,370)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

#################################################################################################################################################################################################### End Buttons

#################################################################################################################################################################################################### Start Label
$labelenv = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelenv.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10) 
$labelenv.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$labelenv.Text = "Please Select the Environment"
$labelenv.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$form.Controls.Add($labelenv)

$labelsec1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelsec1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300,60) 
$labelsec1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$labelsec1.Text = "Section 1 - Pre-Reqs"
$labelsec1.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$form.Controls.Add($labelsec1)

$labelsec2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelsec2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300,160) 
$labelsec2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$labelsec2.Text = "Section 2 - Infrastructure"
$labelsec2.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$form.Controls.Add($labelsec2)

$labelsec3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelsec3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300,260) 
$labelsec3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$labelsec3.Text = "Section 3 - Application"
$labelsec3.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$form.Controls.Add($labelsec3)
#################################################################################################################################################################################################### End Label


#################################################################################################################################################################################################### Start Output Box
$Global:OutputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$OutputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,400) 
$OutputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,200) 
$form.Controls.Add($OutputBox)

#################################################################################################################################################################################################### End Label

#################################################################################################################################################################################################### Start ComboBox

$arrayCompany=@("Production", "Pre-Production", "Integration", "Training", "UK-QA", "UK-DEV", "SEA-QA", "SEA-DEV")

$comboBoxCompany = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox 
$comboBoxCompany.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(535,10) 
$comboBoxCompany.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,30) 
$comboBoxCompany.DropDownHeight = 200
$comboBoxCompany.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Controls.Add($comboBoxCompany) 

foreach ($company in $arraycompany) {
                  $comboBoxCompany.Items.Add($company)
                          } 

$comboBoxCompany_SelectedIndexChanged=
{
If ($comboBoxCompany.text -eq "Production") 
{

$global:InputJSON="azuredeploy.parameters.pro.json"
$global:ResourceINF="RG-INF-PRO"
$global:EnvCode="PRO"
$global:Location="UK South"
$global:Region="UK"

}
ElseIf ($comboBoxCompany.text -eq "Pre-Production")
{
$global:test="This has set correctly to Pre-Production"
}

ElseIf ($comboBoxCompany.text -eq "Integration")
{
$global:test="This has set correctly to Integration"
}

ElseIf ($comboBoxCompany.text -eq "Training")
{
$global:test="This has set correctly to Training"
}

ElseIf ($comboBoxCompany.text -eq "UK-QA")
{
$global:test="This has set correctly to UK-QA"
}

ElseIf ($comboBoxCompany.text -eq "UK-DEV")
{
$global:test="This has set correctly to UK-DEV"
}

ElseIf ($comboBoxCompany.text -eq "SEA-QA")
{
$global:test="This has set correctly to SEA-QA"
}

ElseIf ($comboBoxCompany.text -eq "SEA-DEV")
{
$global:test="This has set correctly to SEA-DEV"
}

$form.Controls.Add($listBoxClub)
}
################ MUST CREATE BEFORE ASSIGN ################
$comboBoxCompany.add_SelectedIndexChanged($comboBoxCompany_SelectedIndexChanged)

#################################################################################################################################################################################################### End ComboBox

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
[void] $form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Many Thanks. However i thought thats what i had tried in the line 
                                                                                    
'#$Outputbox.Appendtext = New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment -Name deployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceINF-NET-01 -TemplateFile -Verbose                                                                 
However it didnt work hence the # although that had failed, the write-host commands are more placeholders, ill actually be executing powershell commands, therefore if i could put the console on the form that would equally work. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are not interacting with the GUI TextBox in your functions. The literal `Write-Host` will use the PSHost console in any case.

One thing I found useful to make such things work however, is to declare an **alias**:

```
function Out-Gui($s) {
    $OutbutBox.AppendText($s);
}

Set-Alias -Name Write-Host  -Value Out-Gui  -Scope Global
```

This avoids quite a bit of copypasta (the WinForms construction is quite windy already), and allows the functions/scripts to remain unchanged between CLI and GUI usage. (- I got a more elaborate [Out-Gui function](http://fossil.include-once.org/clickycoloury/artifact/dc92700bff6f0248e772aaa8c7fcb3fc9ff5eb04#~function+Out-Gui) for WPF, btw.)

To capture errors, you must implement `try`/`catch` blocks, a `TRAP`, or capture an `-ErrorVariable` still. Overriding `Out-Default` and streams is not quite as trivial.

Comment: `Overriding ... streams is not quite as trivial.` if even possible at all.

Comment: Many Thanks. However i thought thats what i had tried in the line #$Outputbox.Appendtext = New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment -Name deployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceINF-NET-01 -TemplateFile -Verbose

Comment: @Joe AppendText is a method, not a variable to assign to. If you need to add some object, also cast it via `| Out-String` first.

Comment: so as simple as $outputbox.appendtext = 'some stuff' | out-String

Comment: @Joe Method call, not assignment.

Comment: can you please give me an example to work from, struggling to understand the logic on this - many thanks

Comment: `$OutbutBox.AppendText($text);` or `.AppendText(($obj | Out-String))`. Or you know, `Write-Host $output` and giving the answer a try.